# How much effort do you spend(or should spend) on security for none web-centric applications?

Tags: security

Suppose the app you are working on is specially designed for a customer to meet a particular 'in-house' need, such as data processing of payroll information.  This application will not be distributed publicly and will reside on internal networks only.  (Theoretically the internal network should remain 100% secure.)    How much effort should a developer spend on IA in this case?  Lets say the database is SQL, would you worry about preventing an SQL injection attack in this situation?

I would love to hear some feedback from developers who work on none web-centric (I can't think of a better term right now, though none web-centric is not completely right.  Its more like none distributed or none public or something along those lines.) type programs and how much effort do they put into security.

**As an addendum, how would you justify this need to a manager type?**

I am currently doing a case study of the necessity of IA for 'in house' software development so any answer would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to take the perspective that no matter what the final use of the product might be, as the application developer I am responsible for ensuring the integrity of the application and its security. This provides two definite benefits:

1. Prevents bugs that you might not / will not foresee. For example the same code that escapes inputs before database queries also ensures that names like O'Leary won't break the application's normal execution.
2. Prevents malicious exploitation of #1.

Regarding #2, if you are working for the company as their developer and information is leaked by an employee using the system then they likely bear liability in that the software is their product. If you are working for a third party that is developing the software to be used by this company then if information is leaked from the company through security holes in your software, any guesses where they'll turn for answers? Either way, it all comes back to you as the application architect and someone with questions about why the application wasn't more secure to begin with.

I would suggest that you implement the most rigorous security possible given your constraints and the sensitivity of the data that you'll be safeguarding. If its high scores for WoW then I'd worry less than if I were designing an internal application for a bank.

Comment: I've never had to. But that would all depend on whether or not the server that your code was located on was secure.

Answer (score 3):

I would apply the "What's the worst thing that could happen" principle to this.  If it means that personal information could be leaked and/or possible legal action could be taken upon the company, you should take the most appropriate action to secure the application.

Comment: That raises an interesting point though.  If an employee wanted to break into the system and information is leaked, is the company liable?  So during development, should we treat it as if we are releasing the program to the general public and have to incorporate all security precautions?

Comment: employee A exploits a weakness to expose confidential information about employee B. employee B proves the information came from the app and sues the company.  Depends how good the company's lawyers are.

It's why most HR systems are paper-based and locked under key.

Answer (score 1):

I have been into the development of some in-house projects. It was an application for collecting the blood group details of the employees and some of their personal information. 
The security part was a bit ignored.

We got a mail from the Internal security team asking us to secure the application, since it had some personal information. It is possible that we accept vendors and expose the application and its always advised to develop the secure code.

Answer (score 1):

As per most security questions the questions you need to ask are.

1. What are the assets you are protecting?
2. Who would want to get at these assets?
3. What is the cost to you/your client/your business if these assets are lost.

Payroll information you mentioned in the question would be the asset you are protecting, would any one whit in your network be interested and not authorised to access this information? What would you say if you found your work mate was being paid twice as much as you?. What would happen if someone managed to update this information would it leed to more money in their bank account?

It is these questions you need to ask when determining how much time to spend on security.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an ancient question, but I came across it looking for academic material, and in my opinion none of the answers are even close to good quality.  So, in hopes that it will help others that find this question:

https://www.cgisecurity.com/owasp/html/ch03.html

Risk analysis in terms of security is complicated.  There are two problems.  First, you have an asset you want to protect.  Second, that asset has a value, and if you *don't* do any risk analysis, you will either end up having security that is too weak and results in significant losses, or you will end up spending significantly more on security than you should, and you will lose money that way.

A rule of thumb I've seen a few times in educational material on physical security is that your security should cost around 10% of the value of the asset you are protecting.  In terms of digital security though, it can be difficult to assess the value of assets.  The above article discusses valuation of digital assets in terms of security.  [Papers on digital security specifically](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220593665_The_Economics_of_Information_Security_Investment) suggest that you should never spend more 37% of the value of losses that would occur if there were a breach, and in most cases the limit should be much lower than that.

So the answer to your first question is: The level of security should be based on the potential losses that could occur if the security was breached, probably valued between 10% and 37% of the potential losses.  In addition, the higher the odds of a breach, the more resources should be spent on security.  A payroll system that isn't public facing should probably go on the low end of that, closer to the 10%, but because the potential losses of a successful attack on a system that literally sends money out to people automatically is pretty high, security spending should be substantial.

As far as how to get management on board, show them the article.  Do the analysis according to the formulas provided.  Use the second paper to show that security spending should be a small but significant percentage of the potential loss value that was calculated using the math in the article.  From there, provide an estimate of the labor costs of the security measures, which will likely be significantly lower than the recommended spending on security, and point out that what you want is *below* the reasonable minimum given the risk analysis.  If you can help them to feel like they are *saving the company money* by doing what you want, that is much more likely to get their buy-in.  But also keep in mind that if you go too far below the reasonable minimum, you are still leaving security too low given the risk.  So don't go *too* cheap, if you actually care about the security, or it may not matter in the end, because you could end up leaving other holes open.  An expensive lock on the front door with no lock on the backdoor isn't 50% less secure than locks on both doors.  It's more like 99% less secure, because anyone who *really* wants to get in will try both doors.